# Undoing C syntax mangling macros to make exctags able to create prototype tags

Tags: header-file, macro, ctags

I can successfully create a `tags` file for vim with exctags (*Exuberant Ctags*).

However, creating tags allowing to **jump to the prototype** of a function does not work, due the system headers using a syntax-mangling macro of the form

```
#define _EXFUN(name, proto)     name proto
```

and in, e.g. `string.h` using

```
char    *_EXFUN(strchr,(const char *, int));
```

which creates a tag for `_EXFUN` instead of `strchr`:

```
_EXFUN  /somedir/include/string.h   /^char  *_EXFUN(strchr,(const char *, int));$/;"    p
```

I create tags with this command:

```
exctags -f tags.p --language-force=c --c-kinds=p file1 file2 ...
```

I've read the exctags man page up and down, tried various `-I` options to affect macro expansions but to no avail. Has anyone solved this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To handle that particular macro, you could use the `--regex-<LANG>` option:

```
ctags --regex-c='/^[^#]*_EXFUN *\( *([^ ,]+),.*/\1/p/' ...
```

Which generates a `tags` file with:

```
_EXFUN  test.c     1;"     d       file:
strchr  test.c     /^char    *_EXFUN(strchr,(const char *, int));$/;"      p
```

Comment: That's a beautifully concise solution! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 5):

Run `ectags` on the preprocessed file, and ask it to look at the preprocessor's comments (`--line-directives=yes`) and to write line numbers into the `tags` file (`-n` or `--excmd=numbers`).

```
cc -E prog.c >prog.p
ectags --line-directives=yes --language-force=c --c-kinds=p -n prog.p
```

Sample C file:

```
#define _EXFUN(name, proto)     name proto

char    *_EXFUN(strchr,(const char *, int));
```

Resulting `tags` file:

```
!_TAG_FILE_FORMAT       2       /extended format; --format=1 will not append ;" to lines/
!_TAG_FILE_SORTED       1       /0=unsorted, 1=sorted, 2=foldcase/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_AUTHOR    Darren Hiebert  /dhiebert@users.sourceforge.net/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_NAME      Exuberant Ctags //
!_TAG_PROGRAM_URL       http://ctags.sourceforge.net    /official site/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_VERSION   5.8     //
strchr  prog.c  3;"     p       file:
```

As you can see, the prototype for `strchr` is listed as occurring on line 3 in `prog.c`.

The *downside* with this is that you don't get any tag entries for preprocessing macros.

You can solve that through running `ectags` on both the preprocessed and original files though:

```
ectags --line-directives=yes --language-force=c --c-kinds=pd -n -I _EXFUN prog.p prog.c
```

which produces

```
[...]
_EXFUN  prog.c  1;"     d       file:
strchr  prog.c  3;"     p       file:
```

Comment: Preprocessing is a very interesting idea! Thanks and +1!